# how to extend WPF GridRow Contents into next row without expanding the current row

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, grid, wpfdatagrid

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to build a dropdown menu using the expander.  Page layout is being handled with a `Grid`.

The extender sits inside the first row of the grid and I would I would like the contents of the expander to expand over top of the contents of everything below when it's clicked.  Unfortunately, right now, the entire row is expanded to accommodate the height of the expanded control.

I tried playing around with the `ZIndex` of the `Expander` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  No matter what, the row always expands forcing everything else on the page to move.

```
<Expander FontSize="18" Name="moduleSelect" Width="100" Header=" Goto -> " 
          Background="#000033" MouseEnter="moduleSelect_MouseEnter" 
          MouseLeave="moduleSelect_MouseLeave" Foreground="White"
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="btnTasks" Width="100" Foreground="White"
                Background="#000033">Tasks</Button>
        <Button Name="btnNotes" Width="100" Foreground="White"
                Background="#000033">Notes</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

How can I make this expand 'above' the subsequent rows without distorting the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if you set the `Grid.RowSpan` of the `Expander` to `2` (or how ever many rows you'd like it to span when expanded)?

So, for a two-row grid, you'd have something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" /> <!--set this to the height of the expander's header area-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WhateverGoesInRow2 Grid.Row="1" />
    <Expander FontSize="18" Name="moduleSelect" Width="100" Header=" Goto -> " 
        Background="#000033" MouseEnter="moduleSelect_MouseEnter" 
        MouseLeave="moduleSelect_MouseLeave" Foreground="White"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Grid.Row=0 Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="btnTasks" Width="100" Foreground="White" Background="#000033">Tasks</Button>
            <Button Name="btnNotes" Width="100" Foreground="White" Background="#000033">Notes</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

You may need to adjust your `RowDefinition` section for your particular situation, but if I'm understanding your problem correctly, I think this will work.

Comment: Won't that push everything in the column down one row while the Expander is open?

Comment: @Robert, It shouldn't. That's the whole point `Grid.RowSpan="2"`. It makes an object occupy both rows of the `Grid`. By setting the height of the grid to the height of the header, when you open the expander, all the overflow (the popped-open stuff) will go into the second row.

Comment: @Robert, I just made a minor edit to my answer. I think the Z-order is dependent on what you put in your XAML first (although you can probably override it if you want), so I put the `WhateverGoesInRow2` before the expander. This should make the expander appear above the other stuff when it is open.

Comment: Neither setting rowspan to 2 or moving the Expander definition to the bottom of the Grid contents works.  I also set the Z-Index in my code onMouseEnter but that didn't work either.  In every case, the row expands instead of rendering the menu on top.

Using ContexMenu or Combobox will work but I was looking for a simple way to do it without having to restyle any controls.  If I could just get it to display over top of the Grid, the expander would be perfect.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, after playing around with the ToggleButton / Popup approach, I was able to make it look and work the same as the expander.  This seems to be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You want something that pops up over the grid, not expands within the grid.  A `ComboBox`, say, or - this being a menu, after all - a `ContextMenu`.

You could also build some combination of a `ToggleButton` and a `Popup`, but that's essentially the same thing as a `ComboBox` with `IsEditable` turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in drop-down control makes use of a Popup control in its default control template to do a similar thing.